# How to display the custom message in SDL Tridion Message bar?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to display my custom message (Say for Ex: some message needs to display when Page is save event is triggered) in SDL Tridion CME Message bar. How to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From an event system you can only display ERROR messages.

If your Event code throws an error the "Message" will be displayed in the Message bar.

For other type of messages you need to use Javascript/CM Extensions. You can find an example of an event system that shows a message [here](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html).

Answer (score 8):

Nuno covered your options pretty well.

If you want to show a message from your ***JavaScript*** code, this is usually my starting point:

```js
$messages.registerNotification("Hello world");
```

If you put this in your JavaScript code (or just paste it into a JavaScript console), it will show a blue bar with "Hello World" in it.

There are many types of messages, each of which shows up slightly differently. What I usually do if I need more than a notification is:

1. type `$messages.` in a JavaScript console in a browser where the web GUI is loaded
2. go through the list of relevant methods to see what looks most promising (they all start with `register`)
3. perform a text search on the source code for the method that I am looking for

This leads me to an example of how that method is used in the GUI already and is a great starting point for my own code.

**Update**

Alexander Klock recently wrote a thorough [explanation of the message types available](http://codedweapon.com/2012/10/anguilla-framework-adding-messages-with-messagecenter/) on his blog.